# Reading And Writing to CSV in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

In oracle DB I have a table say T which has columns id, att1, att2, att3. Now i also have a CSV file which has lots of id's in it along with one additional parameter.How to insert att2 corresponding to each id in the DB.
initially, csv is like

```
   id, random
   id, random
   .
   .
```

i.e after running the PL/SQL script csv file will look like:

```
   id, random, att2
   id, random, att2
   .
   .
   .
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example.

As a prerequisite, connected as a privileged user (SYS), I'm creating a directory (Oracle object) which points to a director on my disk, granting required privileges to user which will be using it. Also, I'm granting EXECUTE on UTL_FILE package to the same user.

```
SQL> connect sys/pwd@xe as sysdba
Connected.
SQL> create directory ext_dir as 'c:\temp';

Directory created.

SQL> grant read, write on directory ext_dir to hr;

Grant succeeded.

SQL> grant execute on utl_file to hr;

Grant succeeded.

SQL>
```

Input file is called SPORT.TXT and looks like this:

```
SQL> $type c:\temp\sport.txt
10,handball
20,football
30,tennis
```

A procedure, which utilizes UTL_FILE to read from and write into files, creates the SPORT_OUT.TXT file which has another value inserted between the first two values of the input file.

It contains comments, I hope you'll be able to follow the execution.

```
SQL> connect hr/hr@xe
Connected.
SQL> declare
  2    -- input and output file types
  3    l_file_in      utl_file.file_type;
  4    l_file_out     utl_file.file_type;
  5    -- directory object
  6    l_dir          varchar2(30) := 'EXT_DIR';
  7    -- input and output file name
  8    l_filename_in  varchar2(30) := 'sport.txt';
  9    l_filename_out varchar2(30) := 'sport_out.txt';
 10    -- the whole line from the input file
 11    l_text         varchar2(32767);
 12    -- ID from the input file
 13    l_id           varchar2(3);
 14    -- your "random" value from the input file
 15    l_random       varchar2(30);
 16    -- value from a table which will be inserted between L_ID and L_RANDOM
 17    l_dname        departments.department_name%type;
 18  begin
 19    -- open files
 20    l_file_in := utl_file.fopen(l_dir, l_filename_in, 'r', 32767);
 21    l_file_out := utl_file.fopen(l_dir, l_filename_out, 'w', 32767);
 22
 23    -- loop through input file
 24    begin
 25      loop
 26        -- fetch line by line
 27        utl_file.get_line(l_file_in, l_text, 32767);
 28        -- extract ID and "random" value
 29        l_id := substr(l_text, 1, instr(l_text, ',') - 1);
 30        l_random := substr(l_text, instr(l_text, ',') + 1, 30);
 31
 32        -- select value from DEPARTMENTS that matches the L_ID value
 33        select max(department_name )
 34          into l_dname
 35          from departments
 36          where department_id = l_id;
 37
 38        -- write line into the output file
 39        utl_file.put_line(l_file_out, l_id ||','||l_dname||','||l_random);
 40      end loop;
 41    exception
 42      when no_data_found then
 43        null;
 44    end;
 45    -- close files
 46    utl_file.fclose(l_file_in);
 47    utl_file.fclose(l_file_out);
 48  end;
 49  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Let's check the result:

```
SQL> $type c:\temp\sport_out.txt
10,Administration,handball
20,Marketing,football
30,Purchasing,tennis

SQL>
```

Seems to be OK, kind of; now, this is just a simple example. It would be OK if you read UTL_FILE documentation and further explore its capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

`UTL_FILE` is a good option for such tasks.

There is also another option, `EXTERNAL TABLE`, but you cannot write to a CSV file using it.

Make sure you have `CREATE DIRECTORY` privilege, which is the most important first step for both these options.

Refer this link for more details:

https://oracle-base.com/articles/9i/external-tables-9i